# Send JSON data from one component to another on button click in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having a form in react consisting of multiple fields. I wish to send the data to another component, basically load another component on button click. This is how I am handling the form

```
FormComponent.tsx:
     const firstName = React.useRef(null);
     const lastName = React.useRef(null);
     const emailAddress = React.useRef(null);
     const password = React.useRef(null);
     const handleSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault();

          const data = {
               firstName: firstName.current.value,
               lastName: lastName.current.value,
               emailAddress: emailAddress.current.value,
               password: password.current.value,
          }
          console.log(data);
     }
 
     ....
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <input type="text" ref={firstName} name="firstName"  required />
         <input type="text" ref={lastName} name="lastName"  required />
         <input type="text" ref={email} name="email"  required />
         <input type="text" ref={password} name="password"  required />
     <Button>Submit</Button>
```

I am able to store the formData temporarily using above approach, but would like to send this to data to another component: 'Second.tsx' which also responds to a Router: '/second'

I have considered using localStorage, but would like to see some effective ways of handling this.

Comment: do you want to pass data object?

Comment: yes, I am currently populating the data object with all the formData collected and would like to pass it to another component somehow.

Comment: The best approach will be to use redux store. So when you click on submit, it will be stored in the redux store and in the 2nd component render, you could fetch the store data and display